# Can't install some POE perl module in Strawberry Perl

Tags: perl, installation, cpan

I've inherited a Perl project that uses a number of Perl modules. I've been trying to set up the environment, but it's been a nightmare. I'm now on day two of just trying to install the modules. The developer who's handing this off said he was able to install everything in about half an hour, and he never saw any of these problems.

```
My Environment: 
    Windows 10 Enterprise 20H2
    Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10850H CPU @ 2.70GHz
    32GB
    64 bit
    Strawberry Perl revision 5 version 32 subversion 1
```

Using CPAN Client, I've been able to install a number of modules without any issue. CPAN::Author, Test::MockObject, pp, Tk, Archive::Any, and a few others all just worked. However, POE has been a disaster.

Most times, I get stuck with a "can't move" failure:

```
cpan[1]> install POE
Database was generated on Tue, 26 Jul 2022 14:02:23 GMT
Running install for module 'POE'
Checksum for C:\strawberry\cpan\sources\authors\id\B\BI\BINGOS\POE-1.370.tar.gz ok
Scanning cache C:\strawberry\cpan\build for sizes
............................................................................DONE
Couldn't move C:\strawberry\cpan\build\tmp-12468\POE-1.370\lib to C:\strawberry\cpan\build\POE-1.370-0\lib: No such file or directory; #82295? CPAN::VERSION=2.28; File::Copy::VERSION=2.34; C:\strawberry\cpan\build\tmp-12468\POE-1.370\lib exists; C:\strawberry\cpan\build\POE-1.370-0\lib does not exist; cwd=C:/strawberry/cpan/build/tmp-12468;
```

I've run cpan from the command line, I've run the CPAN Client, I've run both variations as administrator, and nothing seems to work.

I've tried the "copy-hacked.pm" fix described at https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=82295

On some occasions, after blowing away all CPAN\BUILD\POE* directories, tmp* directories and POE*.yml files, rebooting, and running CPAN Client as administrator, I have actually gotten it (sometimes) to actually start installing/building, but then it gets stuck at "t/10_units/04_drivers/01_sysrw.t................1/17", where it sits for over an hour before we kill it.

I've tried copying the CPAN\build\POE*.* directories and POE*.yml files from the other developer, and run reload index/reload cpan, but that doesn't work, either.

Everyone else is just saying "*it works for me*", which doesn't really help.

Does anyone have **any** idea how I can force an installation of POE? Unfortunately, everything I'm finding online just says "*all you have to to is run CPAN POE*", so there's not much beyond that.

Needless to say, "debug perl installation process" wasn't part of the handoff plan, but right now we have no idea how to proceed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've never done the following with that module, or on that system, but a thought: Try to install from sources? Follow the instructions step by step.  At least it may provide a  better idea of what the problem is.

Comment: I *can* reproduce. Can't debug right now, though

Comment: Basically, it involves going to the build dir (or downloading the tar bar and starting the installation process), then using `perl -d -Mblib t/10_units/04_drivers/01_sysrw.t` (or however you debug).

Comment: Look at output `C:\strawberry\cpan\build\POE-1.370-0\lib does not exist` -- you need to figure out why installation experience difficulty to create this folder (You have mentioned that you run `cpan` as administrator, it is not clear why installation can not create the folder).

Comment: [It has already been reported](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=133627)

Comment: @Polar Bear That problem was resolved

Comment: I've updated the ticket. Basically, the test needs a non-blocking handle, but it uses a pipe which can't be made non-blocking. So you could theoretically force the installation of the module if that's the only issue. (The rest of the test suite runs fine for me.)

Comment: Hi all. It looks like there's no quick and easy fix. I'm not sure where the sources for POE *are*, to be honest. The only instructions I got were "run CPAN POE".

I renamed my C:\Strawberry directory and copied over the other developer's C:\Strawberry installation, and that appears to work. It's a hack, but it's got things running. Unfortunately that won't be of much help to anyone else who experiences the same problem.